# Navigation not going to the named route

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change routes to a different navigator using that navigators key, but when navigating to that other navigator, nothing happens

```dart
Navigator(
      key: Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context, listen: false).firstKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (context) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case '/':
                return FirstPage();
              case '/second':
                return SecondPage();
              default:
                throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Another page:

```dart
Navigator(
      key: Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context, listen: false).secondKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (context) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case '/':
                return ThirdPage();
              case '/fourth':
                return Fourth();
              default:
                throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

While in the second navigator section of the app, I try to change the page using the context:

```dart
final BuildContext firstContent = Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context, listen: false).firstContent.currentContext;
Navigator.of(firstContent).pushNamed('/');
```

Seems like the code in that route is getting called, (added a `print` and it ran), but the visual screen is staying on the same page.

Comment: I think you r still on the first page

Comment: @jitsm555 Nopes, on a diff route. I also have an `IndexedStack` where everything lives in. Thinking that may be causing the issue?